# How to extract keys of a dictionary based on the keys' string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary of variables, as a result of an optimization run. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIA7i.jpg

I would like to extract the values of the keys where the l index is 0 ( `l as in 'FEq_(i,_j,_k,_l)'`) , in order to multiply them with value A, and extract the values of the keys where `l!=0` in order to multiply them with value B.

I have been trying like this:

```
for l in [0]:
    print(varsdict["FEq_({0},_{1},_{2},_{3})".format(i,j,k,l)])
```

but this is not working as the rest of the indexes do not iterate consequently over all their initial range values. I also could not find something of a similar nature where I looked. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you're trying to extract the `_l` element of your key (which I assume is a string) you can just parse the string: `int(("FEq_({0},_{1},_{2},_{3})").split(',')[3][2:3])` will extract the last element which is 3.

Comment: @Peyman sorry if the question was confusing. What I want is to get the values of the keys where `l=0` , so in my case `FEq_(0,_0,_0,_0) and FEq_(0,_0,_3,_0)` in order to further manipulate them. And the same for the values of the keys where `l!=0`. I can do it manually for these 5 keys of my dumbed down problem, but for a more complex problem this is impractical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the values where `l == '0'`:

`vals_0 = [varsdict[k] for k in varsdict if k.split('_')[-1][:-1] == '0']`

To extract the other values (where `l` has any value other than 0):

`other_vals = [varsdict[k] for k in varsdict if k.split('_')[-1][:-1] != '0']`

**Explanation:**
Since your dictionary keys are strings with the format `'FEq_(i,_j,_k,_l)'`, using `split('_')` will return a list with the pieces between occurrences of `'_'`, i.e. `['FEq', '(i,', 'j,', 'k,', 'l)']`.

We then use `[-1]` to select the last element in this list, that is, the string `'l)'`.

Now we use slicing `[:-1]` to select all characters in this string except for the last one (which will be the `)` character), finally returning `'l'`.

Note that this will work no matter how many characters are contained in `l`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Do you know how I could multiply the values of the keys where `l==0` with respective 4-index values? For example I want `FEq_(0,_0,_0,_0) and FEq_(0,_0,_3,_0)` multiplied with `A[0,0,0,0] and A[0,0,3,0]`. And the same for values with keys where `l!=0`, e.g. `FEq_(0,_0,_2,_2)` multiplied with `B[0,0,2,2]` etc etc for all my keys.